# Merge multiple form data

Tags: html, forms

I'm creating a credit card payment page with django.  The user has the option of filling out the credit card info or using a previously entered card.  However the user MUST select a location.

is there a way to create the form so i don't have to have 2 seperate location "select" buttons?

HTML:

```
    <h1>Charge $10 with Stripe</h1>
    <!-- to display errors returned by createToken -->
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" size="30" autocomplete="off" name="fullname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" size="30" autocomplete="off" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" size="11" autocomplete="off" name="phone" />
        </div>

        {% endif %}
        <label>Location</label>
        <select name="location">
        <option value="muir">Muir</option>
        <option value="erc">ERC</option>
        <option value="marshall">Marshall</option>
        <option value="warren">Warren</option>
        <option value="revelle">Revelle</option>
        <option value="sixth">Sixth</option>

        </select>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>CVC</label>
            <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="card-cvc" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
            <input type="text" size="2" class="card-expiry-month"/>
            <span> / </span>
            <input type="text" size="4" class="card-expiry-year"/>
        </div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="save_card_info" value="yes"/> Save this card </br>
        {% endif %}
        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit Payment</button>
    </form>

    {% if user.is_authenticated and user.get_profile.stripe_customer_id %}
    </br>
    OR:
    </br>
    </br>
    Use card ending with: 4343
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label>Location</label>
        <select name="location">
        <option value="muir">Muir</option>
        <option value="erc">ERC</option>
        <option value="marshall">Marshall</option>
        <option value="warren">Warren</option>
        <option value="revelle">Revelle</option>
        <option value="sixth">Sixth</option>
        </select>
        </br>
        <input type="hidden" name="action=" value="pay_saved_card"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>

    </form>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the selected location via JavaScript (probably quite easily when using jQuery) in the respective form's submit event handler.